# Can I build mdpi/hdpi combined APK with every density drawables?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

My project has two targets. (neither for Play Store, so `aab` cannot be the solution)

- Target 1: Normal version for every densities. **(ldpi, ..., xxxhdpi)**
- Target 2: Tablet specific version for mdpi/hdpi densities. **(mdpi, hdpi)**

Of course, I can use all resources version for all, but Target 2 has apk size issue. Furthermore, my client wants just single apk for Target 2.
My last solution is splitting into two branches, but I think it would be great to achieve this goal via gradle settings. However, gradle `split` settings generates two apks per densities(**mdpi, hdpi**).
Any ideas?

Comment: why dont u use svg drawables and constraint layout they work everywhere

Comment: FYI, designers belongs to client. I can't control them. Also lots of photos included (so apk size has been issued as a result). Network is very limited for Target 2. Sadly, I don't have much authorities on this project.

Comment: give them a suggestion... tell them how things can be done in a better way